# Pandas Dataframe from Web page

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a group of images from a webpage using beautifulsoup and pandas, but I'm stuck with a passage.

Since the [site](http://www.mariaberica.it/4.Quadri%20per%20sito.htm) was coded with Microsoft Word and has an uncomfortable format, I plan to convert it into a pd.DataFrame where the path of all images could be linked with appropriated description.

I've managed to print to shell all the infos I need, but I can't load them into  a list, or into a dataframe.

Could you help?

Here is the code:

```
# Import packages
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify url
url = 'http://mariaberica.it/4.Quadri per sito.htm'

# Package the request, send the request and catch the response: r
r = requests.get(url)

# Extracts the response as html: html_doc
html_doc = r.text

# create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML: soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

# Find all 'a' tags (which define hyperlinks): a_tags

a_tags = soup.find_all('img')


# Print the URLs to the shell
for link in a_tags:
    print(link.get('src'))
```

Here is what I get in the Shell. I'd like to have it on a list.

```
4.Quadri%20per%20sito_file/image001.jpg
4.Quadri%20per%20sito_file/image002.jpg
4.Quadri%20per%20sito_file/image003.jpg
4.Quadri%20per%20sito_file/image004.jpg
```

Could you help?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the issue is? Are you familiar with the basics of lists? Have you consulted the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `list comprehension` to get that into a list.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://mariaberica.it/4.Quadri per sito.htm'
a_tags = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser").find_all('img')
image_src = [l["src"] for l in a_tags]
print(image_src[:2])
```

Sample output of the first two elements:

```
['4.Quadri%20per%20sito_file/image001.jpg', '4.Quadri%20per%20sito_file/image002.jpg']
```